# Upgrading to PHP 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I have php 5.6.30 installed and running alongside nginx 1.12.1 on ubuntu 14.04.5

I want to run laravel 5.5 so I need to get php7+ and several php extensions.

Here is how I try to install them

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-curl php7.1-json php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-opcache php7.1-xml php7.1-cgi php7.1-common php7.1-fpm php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mysql php7.1-readline php7.1-xmlrpc
```

Last message says "`php7.1-fpm start/running, process 24107`"

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.10-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

But it does **not** have a socket file:

```
$ ls /var/run/php                                                                                                                                                  
php5.6-fpm.pid  php5.6-fpm.sock
```

So I try several things:

```
$ service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx

$ service php7.1-fpm start
php7.1-fpm start/running, process 4426
```

But still:

```
$ ls /var/run/php                                                                                                                                                  
php5.6-fpm.pid  php5.6-fpm.sock
```

I have tried reinstalling several times yet I get the the same situation. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - for some reason my initial php7 installation was corrupted.
Then I was uninstalling it using `apt-get remove php7.0 php...` and leaving some corrupt files behind

It finally worked when I used `apt-get purge php7.0 php...` to nuke them all and reinstall.